# What is localhost address for android on port:81?

Tags: android, xampp

I am running xamp on port 81.
i am using 10.0.2.2 but error is giving no host found.
what is address for android  on port 81.

localhost:81/

Comment: have you tried with localhost:81 instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: @Vamshi yes i tried , not works

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this **10.0.2.2:81**.It will work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, browsers (and not only them) let you specify the port `host:port`, which defaults to `80`.

Then, is 10.0.2.2 the IP address of the device running xampp? `localhost` obviously works only if you call the server on the same host as the client.

If `x.y.z.w` is the IP address then you’ll have to enter `x.y.z.w:81` in your browser.

You should check the IP address of your server in its settings, and use it.